# PHP in_array issue

Tags: php, html

so im messing around with some php and for some reason in_array() won't pickup if something is within the array, correctly?

index.php:

```
<form action="login.php" method="get">
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

login.php:

```
    <?php
    $username = $_GET["username"];
    $password = $_GET["password"];
        include('data/user_data.php');
        if(in_array($username, $users)):
            echo "in array";
        else: echo "not in array";
        endif;

?>
```

user_data.php:

```
<?php $users = array(
dextermb => array("dextermb", "password"),
tonymb => array("tonymb", "password2")
)
?>
```

When inputting "dextermb" or "tonymb" into username and submitting I get the result "not in array" even though it is in the array?

Thoughts on what might be the issue?

Comment: You can't use in_array() with a nested array. array_key_exists would work fro you though.

Comment: Go with `$users = array('dextermb' => 'password1', 'tonymb' => 'password2');`

Comment: using in_array() in login check in not an optimal solution....
use db call instead of...

Comment: Hope you're only fiddling with it - please make sure hard-coded username/password pairs won't end up in production ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your users array:

```
$users = array(
    'dextermb' => array("dextermb", "password"),
    'tonymb' => array("tonymb", "password2")
);
```

Then you want to simply do:

```
if(isset($users[$username])) {
```

Or alternatively:

```
if(array_key_exists($username, $users)) {
```

The username is the key in your `$users` array, the `in_array` method looks for values (and not nested values).

Comment: Ah nice! Thats a nice way of doing it, probably would be easier to search the array using isset, rather than array_key_exists? *for example matching the password with the name?

Comment: @Night That seems simplest to me, yeah

Comment: As the password is always going to be the second position in the array, wouldn't you be able to search it by something like "$users[$username,2]" (I know my example doesn't work)

Comment: @Night $users[$username][1] would get the password for that user

Answer (score 0):

**Simply You can use a php built in function**

```
     if(array_key_exists($username, $users)){
     echo "in array";
     }else{
          echo "not in array";
     }
```